# Formula for deviation from mean agreement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a dataset in Excel and I want to compute a formula for deviation from mean agreement.

Suppose the dataset is like this:

```
A    B    C    D    E

4    2         6    9
1         3    2    
     7    2         1
8         4    3    
     5         1    2
```

What I want to calculate has formula as `(summation from i=1 to 5 (i.e., from A to E) |R-R'|/t)/N` where `N = 4` for 1st row, `N = 3` for 2nd row and so on that is, no. of non null values for that row. `R` is current value in the row and `R'` is mean of the column for which we are considering `R` and `t` is no. of non null values in that vertical or column.

Comment: Can you give the example of what you want your output to look like?

Comment: You really don't want to know what I have tried because I have no prior experience of working with Excel formulae. I can make and use simple formulae but not this complex.

Comment: Regarding output, for first row it should be   (  (|4-13/3|/3)+(|2-14/3|/3)+(|6-12/4|/4)+(|9-12/3|/3)  ) /4 for 1st row and so on for other rows. where 13/3 is mean for 1st column, 14/3 for 2nd column and so on.   This process repeats for each row. I would like to get the formula to write in the formula bar in Excel.

Comment: You should provide *at least* some testing data.

Comment: You could use the data in question as your testing data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [ABS()](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/logical-functions.html) function to get the absolute value of the subtractions. To get the number of non-null cells you can use the [COUNT()](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/logical-functions.html) function. To only include items in a row that are not null you can use an [IF()](http://www.excel-easy.com/functions/logical-functions.html) statement.

For example, if you data was in the range A1:E5 then the following formula would get the result for the first row if I've understood the calculation you are doing correctly:

```
=(IF(LEN(A1)>0,(ABS(A1-SUM(A$1:A$5))/COUNT(A$1:A$5)))+IF(LEN(B1)>0,(ABS(B1-SUM(B$1:B$5))/COUNT(B$1:B$5)))+IF(LEN(C1)>0,(ABS(C1-SUM(C$1:C$5))/COUNT(C$1:C$5)))+IF(LEN(D1)>0,(ABS(D1-SUM(D$1:D$5))/COUNT(D$1:D$5)))+IF(LEN(E1)>0,(ABS(E1-SUM(E$1:E$5))/COUNT(E$1:E$5))))/COUNT($A1:$E1)
```

Which results in 2.4853 for row 1

Comment: Well my dataset also contains negatives and zeroes and there are 100 columns and it should be ABS(A1-AVG(A$1:A$5)) because I am asking for mean not sum. Is there any way where I can just write a formula that finds this value for all rows and I don't have to sum for all the columns like you suggested.

Comment: Sure if you can use the LEN() function inside the IF statements to ignore blank values. I have updated my answer to show this. This formula will work assuming you have 5 rows of data starting in row 1, if you have more than 5 rows update the 5's to $<last row> accordingly. Once you have entered this formula for the first row you can copy+paste or drag down as required

Comment: I get it for row part and I had already understood it what I am trying to say is I have 100 columns in my dataset and I couldn't possibly write 100 IF's, it is just not feasible and would make formula cumbersome. Is there any way by which I could write one IF and use SUM in some way so as to make it work for other columns too. And by the way, COUNTA is suitable here instead of COUNT.